# position sticky is not working after setting float left of other elements

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, sticky

header `position sticky` is not working after adding `float:left` on the other element. The `position sticky` is working if I remove the `float:left` from `main>div`. I searched it on google but I didn't find any solution for this.  Here is the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
        .header {
            height: 100px;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: pink;
        }

        main>div {
            float: left;
            /*If I don't use it, the sticky header works*/
            height: 1500px
        }

        .first {
            background: linear-gradient(to top, red, yellow);
            width: 300px;
            top: 0;
        }

        .second {
            background: linear-gradient(to top, khaki, gray);
            width: calc(100% - 600px);
        }

        .third {
            background: linear-gradient(to top, tomato, green);
            width: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        sticky header
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="first"></div>
        <div class="second"></div>
        <div class="third"></div>
    </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Check the same code on Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/habibulislam6862/53yv1rzw/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for a layout, you might want to include the `-x-sticky` for browser compatibility and have your column in percentages to make them responsive.

Example, run code snippet below:

```css
body{
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
header {
   height: 60px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: pink;
   position: -webkit-sticky;
   position: -ms-sticky;
   position: -moz-sticky;
   position: -o-sticky;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0px;
   z-index: 1;
}
main {
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   height: 1500px;
}
.first {
   background: linear-gradient(to top, red, yellow);
   min-width: 20%;
}
.second {
   background: linear-gradient(to top, khaki, gray);
   flex-grow: 1;
}
.third {
   background: linear-gradient(to top, tomato, green);
   min-width: 20%;
}
```

```html
   <header>
      sticky header
   </header>
   <main>
      <div class="first"></div>
      <div class="second"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, vitae tincidunt nascetur donec porttitor aenean et nunc, ut dictum inceptos facilisis commodo cum. Duis magnis parturient sollicitudin diam augue placerat imperdiet neque, euismod cum nostra erat lacus et conubia, facilisi pellentesque molestie risus mus dapibus vel. Malesuada vestibulum habitasse class sodales viverra mauris fermentum tortor massa bibendum augue libero, euismod montes sed dis magna vel leo praesent mattis platea eleifend. Neque commodo maecenas odio curae cubilia potenti habitant congue porttitor, integer libero mattis nisl sed mauris donec litora magnis, nulla dignissim platea hac dui varius tellus tincidunt.</p> <p>Dignissim proin arcu magna vitae id nam volutpat natoque semper sem, aliquet erat aliquam sociosqu scelerisque eget urna mollis sagittis. Posuere arcu sociosqu mi ad lacinia vitae ac nascetur tempor pharetra aptent fringilla, turpis sodales himenaeos malesuada mattis nisl diam sapien quisque cum. Enim dictum etiam mollis egestas et magna blandit dignissim, ullamcorper parturient odio suspendisse curabitur habitasse dui facilisi, laoreet ridiculus est ad vehicula curae nullam.</p> <p>Facilisis odio mauris consequat mattis faucibus aliquam eu semper condimentum, imperdiet natoque magna leo malesuada lacinia posuere placerat tellus, suscipit dapibus pharetra porta eros diam feugiat dictum. Suscipit euismod fermentum interdum bibendum nullam porttitor, pharetra dis mollis vivamus leo elementum commodo, facilisi rhoncus aptent ligula maecenas. Sodales pellentesque purus parturient mollis mauris tellus id vehicula, velit ac quam sociosqu molestie sollicitudin neque eleifend, mus porttitor aenean penatibus libero fringilla sagittis.</p> <p>Phasellus ornare eros per nam sollicitudin taciti himenaeos, senectus auctor fusce varius magna hendrerit. Urna proin lacus conubia tortor venenatis mauris nec facilisi, fringilla arcu non accumsan pellentesque neque ut dictum euismod, curae tempor eu felis habitasse mi dui. Viverra vehicula ultrices etiam maecenas fusce pulvinar dis sem litora, luctus molestie suscipit tristique imperdiet gravida pretium augue, vel velit nibh hac mus nam consequat eros.</p> <p>Metus feugiat nisl felis fames condimentum facilisi posuere tempus ultricies scelerisque porttitor aptent, justo tempor magnis ultrices phasellus cras nascetur interdum augue aenean iaculis. Lacinia diam lectus lacus facilisis nisl accumsan magna curae nullam placerat bibendum dictum, vehicula dui integer non viverra iaculis interdum vitae at suscipit egestas. Ac aptent fermentum netus eros vulputate phasellus iaculis, cum inceptos velit suspendisse morbi viverra, ante fringilla faucibus donec placerat nullam. Aliquam diam integer vivamus ligula nam cras cursus tristique libero, mattis nisi vestibulum litora enim suspendisse inceptos fames facilisi, erat penatibus ridiculus taciti duis bibendum tortor ornare.</p> <p>Lectus dui sagittis et nascetur nec hendrerit convallis, dapibus curabitur fermentum varius scelerisque nullam platea, metus elementum mattis id semper dignissim. Ridiculus habitasse at sociosqu gravida dui metus velit aptent praesent, dapibus purus egestas et diam nisi pulvinar porttitor, ullamcorper hac integer cubilia sagittis lobortis justo tristique. Penatibus diam convallis velit sapien, ornare nascetur morbi laoreet vulputate, vitae lectus potenti.</p> <p>Egestas nostra mus montes suscipit morbi mattis vestibulum, sapien penatibus laoreet luctus eu feugiat. Integer a fringilla aenean quisque diam nostra, nisl volutpat commodo augue gravida massa, praesent elementum pulvinar curabitur proin.</p></div>
      <div class="third"></div>
   </main>
```

Answer (score 3):

if you start a "float" you also have to clear it

try adding below line after

```
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

So final code will be as below; Feel free to externalize style into a class

```
    <header class="header">
    sticky header
</header>
<main>
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>
</main>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

you can also use a sudo element  (like "after" in css) to do the same https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

Comment: that's good. but I have got a better way to fix it in another answer.